# Oracle: one or more scripts to provoke a failure on instance

Tags: oracle, database-backups

For educational purposes, i need one or more scripts to provoke a failure on the current instance of Oracle (orcl for example). This way i can be sure that my backups are working accordingly. And yes, **I NEED SCRIPTS**.. so... no manual shutdown of my computer during a query or weird stuff like that.

To give some more context, am using the 19.x.x version of oracle, and using mostly SQLPLUS and RMAN for everything.

Thank you for your time. And,if i can get more than only one type of script, the better.

EDIT 1:

Since am being told of being "off-topic", i clarify. Am trying to save me up a fortune by skipping up a whole semester if i take a "convalidation exam". And what am asking is a point (or goal if you want) of the "summary" of the class. And it literally says: "The student should make one or more scripts so the instance fails and do a proper backup".

And right now am not recieving an answer from the teacher.

Comment: And what is considered, "failure?"  Also, question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO

Comment: If the point is validating your backups - something that can be done with the RMAN backup process itself - then does it really matter *how* a datafile or other file becomes corrupted or lost? RMAN doesn't fix the file in place, it replaces it from the backup set. Just delete a file, establish that the database is down and/or cannot be used, and then restore from backup. Speaking from experience, your RMAN restore will essentially be a manual process - setting the restore point, watching the process to deal with any errors that come up; why must creating your failure scenario be scripted?

Comment: **What's a failure?** Not sure, am trying to get the same on my end. But i guess an example would be a scripts that shutdowns the instance while inserting data on one or more tables; or produce an error by overloading the instance; etc. But i insist, am not sure.

**Why should be scripted?** That's what the "summary of the class" says.

Comment: Please note that any answers you get here will have the license [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) such that when you submit your homework you are legally required to provide attribution back to these answers where you have copied the solution from.

Answer (score 0):

Just raise the appropriate exceptions:

```sql
DECLARE
  tns_listener_not_found EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( tns_listener_not_found, -12154 );
BEGIN
  RAISE tns_listener_not_found;
END;
/
```

or

```sql
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'User specified error.' );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write an SQL*Plus script that deletes the system datafile. The database will fail and the instance very likely, too.

```
SELECT file_name FROM dba_data_files WHERE file_name LIKE '%system%';
```

You store the filename in a variable and delete the file on the operating system, for instance on Unix:

```
rm /opt/oracle/oradata/.../system01.dbf
```

The `HOST` command is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/HOST.html#GUID-E6391C3D-E87E-4BCA-B903-A4402D7E399B), how to store the file name [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-026B5022-3F51-4306-A48C-F12DE48DB174), I am confident that you can do the rest yourself!